# level shifting 5V pulse to 12V pulse

Tags: transistors, mosfet, pwm, level-shifting, push-pull

When I search for level shifting 5V pulse to 12V, I came to know about the circuit given below.
[image]

It is simply based on a push-pull amplifier configuration as you all know. And what I have understood is, when the input reaches 5V (high) level, then Q1 conducts and since it is an NPN transistor, it will make the gate of the MOSFETs both low so that Q3 starts to conduct and vice versa for when an input is 0V. 
When we see a graph in an oscilloscope it will show 12V pulse as in the attached graph given below.

But when input pulse goes low (0V), I cannot see an output voltage at 0V. Instead, I am getting 6.366V in output wave instead of 0V. why does that happen and how to resolve this problem?

[image]

Thanks for the help in advance!

Edit: As per suggestions from the comment, I have attached an output node.

Comment: 1. Which node is the output? 2. Was Q3 upside down like it is in your schematic when you did the simulation?

Comment: Notice the body diode drawn in the Q3 symbol. With that diode in mind, how much current would have to go through the Q2 drain to drive the output low?

Comment: Just curious. Do you want a push-pull driver? If so, what slew rates and what current compliances? How fast and what kind of load must it drive?

Comment: @jonk, I just thought and got curious about how to level shift 5V to 12V when I meet that situation. That's all.

Comment: @ThePhoton, Yes. Q3 was like that when I did a simulation and the output node is shown now.

Comment: @Dhans That's a good enough reason to ask. I was curious. The schematic you show is way over complex, though. Even working. Also, if you don't need "push-pull" at the output (both active LO and active HI), then it can be simplified. You also may not need to use both a push-pull BJT driver pair to drive the gates of a push-pull MOSFET power pair (not that the BSS84 is considered "power".)

Comment: @jonk, Ok. Then what might be the one that replacing BSS84 Mosfet. Are you saying that I have a wrong mosfet for this configuration or wrong connection?

Comment: @Dhans No, I'm not commenting on any of the specific parts you may be considering. Just the topology. You can get by with a single BJT, for example. See: [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/296879/logic-level-converter-using-transistors/297092#297092). Also, for positive and negative output voltage rails, there is [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/317458/level-shift-0-5v-to-10v-10v/317479#317479).

Comment: @Dhans  Or, for a full push-pull, it could similar to [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/346474/driving-capacitance-with-a-high-voltage-level-shifter/346484#346484). And so far, none of these really look like the usual high-side or low-side switching, which can be quite simple, as well. A lot depends on things like "how fast?", "how much drive?", and so on. So there are probably a dozen ways to go right off the top of my head. And given a few more minutes, even more.

Comment: @jonk, Wow. That's interesting. I am loaded now with a lot of circuits with different topologies. I will try that. thanks, sir!

Comment: Actually you see that 6.366v because BSS138K is not in its ohmic region, which looks weird since BSS138K Vgs(th) =~1.0v. So try replacing it by a 2n7000 and flip BSS84P vertically and it´ll probably work.

Comment: @FlávioAlegretti, I will have a look at it and let you know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most apparent serious problem with the circuit is that you have the Source and Drain of this FET wrong way around in the circuit. Note how the body diode will conduct a lot of current when the lower FET tries to pull low.

[image]

If you want a chance of getting a 5V to 12V driver circuit working prepare it more like this configuration and get rid of a couple of transistors in the process.

[image]

Comment: If so, as said in your answer, If I change the mosfet, will it solve a problem?

Comment: @Dhans - Yeah it probably would work but as I've shown in my answer there really is no need for the intermediate BJT pair.

Comment: Yes. I have tested it and then only I accepted your answer.

Comment: Note that the stacked output FETS may see some shoot through current right at the time of switching at the gates. If this is too much you may

Comment: ...may want to put a small resistor in series with the V+ supply above the upper FET in the stack.